# What plant are the vines in the fire swamp?

Tags: movie, object-identification, the-princess-bride

In the movie Princess Bride, Westley and Buttercup flee in to the Fireswamp where Westley uses his sword to cut through vines or vine like plants that are obstructing their path.

What are those vine plants?  Are they (meant to resemble) any true to life plant that actually exists (and if so, which one)?  Or are they merely a cinematic representation of the "jungle vine" trope plant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Princess-Bride,-The.html) indicates that they're hideous (and potentially flesh-eating!) vines.

> **WESTLEY:** *You see, what I told you before about saying "please" was
>   true. It intrigued Roberts, as did my descriptions of your beauty.*
>
> [CUT TO: SOME HIDEOUS VINES -- they look like they could be flesh
>   eating. Westley takes his sword, slices a path for them to follow. The
>   vines groan as they fall. He's been chatting away the entire time.]

As far as the film is concerned, they appear to just be generic tropey [jungle vines](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/VineSwing) unlike those that you find in real life.

[image]

---

The [original book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Princess_Bride) is no help. They're just described as "vines"

> He had cut a
>   very long piece of strong vine and coiled it over one shoulder and was
>   busy working on it as they moved.

etc.

Comment: WOW, that answer was actually far more thoroughly referenced than I ever expected an answer to be ... so much so that I have to ask :  What about the props department records?  What did they actually use to make the vine-rope props for the movie?

Comment: @Dalila - I've reached out to a couple of the people involved in the set-dressing and prop-making for the film to ask them your follow-up question. If I hear back from them, I'll update accordingly.

Comment: I'd really like to know what they say, if they reply.  But even if they don't, that's above and beyond, and the answer, as it stands, is already well deserving to be selected as the right answer !